# SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 68: parser error

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to parse my XML to a MYSQL DB. But I get an error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 68: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hits line 3 and events in ******* on line 72

I think I misspelled something but I can't seem to find it. This is my first time working with XML.

Here is my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo 'single value: <br />';
echo $xml->events->hits->hits->hits->hits[0]->_id; // get single value
```

Here is $xmlstr:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<events>
   <hits>200</hits>
   <hits>
      <_shards>
         <failed>0</failed>
         <successful>5</successful>
         <total>5</total>
      </_shards>
      <hits>
         <hits>
            <hits>
               <_id>2307</_id>
               <_index>events</_index>
               <_score null="true" />
               <_type>event</_type>
               <fields>
                  <description>
                     <hits>Bla</hits>
                  </description>
                  <genres>
                     <hits>
                        <hits>Classic</hits>
                        <hits>Rock</hits>
                        <hits>Pop</hits>
                     </hits>
                  </genres>
                  <header>
                     <hits>https://media.hugo.events/events/2307/56820e2ac5fa1eecf115fc8aaf250e9c.jpg</hits>
                  </header>
                  <logo>
                     <hits>https://media.hugo.events/events/2307/240e3f379e5996ac4c5e20b9c874cc6f.png</hits>
                  </logo>
                  <name>
                     <hits>Cultureel Festival Baarn 2016</hits>
                  </name>
                  <start>
                     <hits>2016-09-02T12:00:00+0000</hits>
                  </start>
                  <venue.city>
                     <hits>Baarn</hits>
                  </venue.city>
                  <venue.country>
                     <hits>Nederland</hits>
                  </venue.country>
                  <venue.location>
                     <hits>5.2906804</hits>
                     <hits>52.210896</hits>
                  </venue.location>
               </fields>
               <sort>
                  <hits>1472817600000</hits>
               </sort>
            </hits>
        </hits>
    </hits>
</events>
XML;
```

Did I do something wrong with pointing at the part that I want to parse?

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error message explains, your XML is invalid. (You start 4 `<hits>` tags and only close 3.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i see your xml is not valid. I also checked it and found a missing closing `</hits>` at the end. Validator used: https://validator.w3.org/check
Also maybe its a nice try adding `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning

Comment: I got rid of the error but now I have another error: 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ******** on line 64

Comment: Line 64 is the last line

Comment: Hey, Your first <hits></hits> is making trouble. try this $xml->events->hits[1]->hits->hits->hits->_id;

Comment: this should work echo $xml->hits[1]->hits->hits->hits->_id;